# CNTK: Workaround for loading pretrained word embeddings from file

Tags: python, cntk

It seems like it is not possible to load pretrained embeddings to a layer. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/1238)

What I did as a workaround is the following:

```
    model = create_model()

    E = [p for p in model.parameters if p.name == 'E'][0]
    emb = np.asarray(np.loadtxt('embeddings.txt', delimiter=' '), dtype='float32')
    model = model.clone(CloneMethod.clone, { E: constant(emb) })
```

with embeddings.txt having the following format where the number of rows is the number of words in the vocabulary I use and the number of columns is the dimensions I have chosen for my embeddings:
-0.05952413007617 0.12596195936203 -0.189506858587265 ... 
-0.0871662572026253 -0.0454806201159954 -0.126074999570847 ...
...

Does the above seem like a correct workaround? 
I kicked off a training session and the number of parameters is reduced compared to what I had when training the embeddings layer which could be a good indication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. For example:

```
# embedding, initialized from a user-supplied constant weight table
e = Embedding(weights=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 1]])

# (you would get the weights from a file instead)

# test it:
y = Input(2)

dat = np.array([[-1., 1.]], dtype=np.float32)
res = e(y).eval({y: dat})

npout = np.matrix(dat[0]) * e.E.value
np.testing.assert_array_equal(res[0], npout, err_msg='Error in constant embedding layer')
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try out: E.value = emb as an alternate workaround.

Your workaround freezes the embedding to a constant. If that is not acceptable and you want to further train the embeddings the above approach might be your choice.